# How to use global variables in imported libraries?

Tags: python

I've a `main.py` file with a block of code like this:

```
import urtc
import machine
rtc = urtc.DS3231(machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin(0), sda=machine.Pin(2)))
from func import *  #line 4
```

Now, `func.py` file which is imported on line 4 has code something like this:

```
def current_time():
    import urtc
    import machine
    rtc = urtc.DS3231(machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin(0), sda=machine.Pin(2)))
    return urtc.tuple2seconds(rtc.datetime())
```

In `main.py`, I'm already importing `urtc` and `machine` and defining `rtc`. Is it possible to eliminate these 3 lines from function `current_time()`:

```
import urtc
import machine
rtc = urtc.DS3231(machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin(0), sda=machine.Pin(2)))
```

It seems redundant as I already have them in `main.py` global. How can I use them from `main.py` global instead of importing them again in function `current_time()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `urtc.DS3231` instance to the `current_time` function like so:

```
def current_time(rtc):
    return urtc.tuple2seconds(rtc.datetime())
```

But you still need to `import urtc` in `func.py` so that `urtc.tuple2seconds` is available.

Comment: This seems to be the only correct option for my current situation. Since I'm adding this code on 96kb RAM device, memory management is a critical issue. Even a few bytes are too much for the device. Thanks for writing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use arguments in your function, this is in fact bad design to do it the way you did.

```
import urtc
import machine
rtc = urtc.DS3231(machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin(0), sda=machine.Pin(2)))
from func import *

def current_time(rtc):
    return urtc.tuple2seconds(rtc.datetime())

current_time(rtc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you load the dependencies in func.py (if you are not using them anywhere else in main.py, it is a better practice).